# Center title in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there any way to center text in `actionbar` without using custom `layout`? Internet is full of custom ways, but I am unable to find solution by using native `actionbar`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Actionbar.Title</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/ab_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="Actionbar.Title"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
</style>


<style name="Theme.Holo" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add:

```
<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
```